# Dynamic Web Reference with a WCF service

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2003, web-reference

I have a WCF service written in .NET 4.  For some reason when you create a Web Reference using Visual Studio 2003 and change the "URL Behavior" from static to dynamic it doesn't seem to be completely working.  The config file changes but the reference.cs file constructor hard codes the Url instead of pulling from AppSettings.

Has anyone else ever had this issue?

Comment: I have this issue too. When I add a reference to a WCF service, but adding it to the project as a "Web Reference" (using .NET 2.0 Web References technology, "Add Service Reference..."-->"Advanced..."-->"Add Web Reference...") the Url is hardcoded, no matter the behavior setting. I have reproduced this with VS2008 and VS2010.